# Excel Pivot Table Inquiry

Tags: excel

[image: Excel capture]I have a pivot table with imported data from a raw data list, which is also filterable between 4 different months. I want to show, in the same pivot table, the averages of last month, the current month, and the average of all four, but every time I change one column, the others change as well. How do I get them to be accurate and act independently? Would offset be the best option. I know this question is rather confusing, but I'm not sure how to even ask the question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create  fórmula the last month based on you Date field.

First you need to create a formula on your data source and named 
"last month":

```
=IF(AND(A2>=EDATE(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),1),-1), A2<=EDATE(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),-1)),D2,0)
```

"the current month":

```
=IF(AND(A2>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),1), A2<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))),D2,0)
```

"the average of all four":

```
=IF(AND(A2>=EDATE(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),1),-4), A2<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))),D2,0)
```

After you create the fórmula you can able to add it to your pivot table as Sum, Average etc...

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your response. If the dates are, let's say, from 2013, do I change the terms Today, Year, and Date?  I forgot to mention, the last two categories I need are not part of the pivot table, just added.

Comment: You can replace "Today()" for the range of your PivotTable that contain the date you want to filter!